# How can I find the original un-changed configuration file to compare with the *.rpmnew file?

Tags: configuration, rpm, update, defaults, upgrade

While upgrading from CentOS 5.7 to 5.8 I've received the following warnings:

```
warning: /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config created as /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config.rpmnew
warning: /etc/ssh/sshd_config created as /etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew
warning: /etc/odbcinst.ini created as /etc/odbcinst.ini.rpmnew
```

(To know the reason for such files, and what one can do with them read - [Why do I have .rpmnew file after an update?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48776/why-do-i-have-rpmnew-file-after-an-update) )

I want to know what exactly has been change in the default config file by comparing the old default file (the original un-changed configuration file) with the new default file (*.rpmnew). Then, I can apply the changes to my modified file (aka diff merge).

The problem is I don't know where can I find the original un-changed configuration file...

**Updated:**

So my question is actually:

1. How to find out what was the previous version of the package?
2. How to get the file of that version?

Comment: It actually says exactly where the original and where the rpmnew files are, right in the warning message: "warning: /etc/ssh/sshd_config created as /etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew"

Comment: @cjc I'm not that fool :) please see updated question

Comment: Ah.  Look for the final versions of the 5.7 packages from http://vault.centos.org/, specifically http://vault.centos.org/5.7/os/i386/CentOS/ and then use the rpm2cpio tool to extract the ones you want to look at, as per johnshen64's answer.  Also look in http://vault.centos.org/5.7/updates/ for updates to any packages in the 5.7 base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the original files should be one without .rpmnew

so for instance, you should have a

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

diff /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew

will show you the diff. rpm does this to prevent overriding your settings.

if you are looking for the previously installed rpm, you need to find that rpm, and then extract it with rpm2cpio and then cpio to unpack the files.

then you should be able to find the default configuration files in the unpacked files.

Comment: I could be wrong but as far as I understand, the OP has modified the original configuration files, so the files on his system (e.g. sshd_config) is modified. The OP is asking how to find the original unmodified ones

Comment: Ah, you are talking about unmodified configuration file of the previously installed rpm? In that case, we have to find the original rpm and extract. This would depend which exact version was installed before the new rpm version was installed. rpms are just archives that can unpacked to find the individual files. rpm2cpio  is the usual tool for that.

Comment: Yeah dvb is right, that what I'm talking about, I would be grateful if you could edit your answer to explain how to find out what was the previous version and how to get the file of that version