# What is the best place to put umask setting for php-fpm in Centos 6?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, centos6, umask

For the following two places of php-fpm init configuration on Centos 6, which one do you think is the most suitable to put in, for example, umask = 077 ?

/etc/init.d/php-fpm

OR

/etc/sysconfig/php-fpm

Any other suggestions are also welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sysconfig script is being sourced from the init script (as it should be), then that's the place to put it.
The init script might get updated at some point, and then you'll have a shiny little `/etc/init.d/php-fpm.rpmnew` file to take a look at. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to confirm, according to what you said, it wouldn't be good to modify the /etc/init.d/php-fpm file since upgrading centos might overwrite the modified file (while saving it as /etc/init.d/php-fpm.rpmnew) and render the change useless?

Comment: It wouldn't overwrite the modified one, but would set aside the new one for you to check before merging the changes manually. See for example, http://serverfault.com/q/48776/78672